# How to handle colon (:) in the name when using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to search a number in a web page (https://muisca.dian.gov.co/WebRutMuisca/DefConsultaEstadoRUT.faces).

I know the name of the input element is: "vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit", however when I try to find the element I got this error:

```
"NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\jcherrerab\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://muisca.dian.gov.co/WebRutMuisca/DefConsultaEstadoRUT.faces")
driver.find_element_by_name("vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit").send_keys("860003020")
```

Can you help me pls?

Comment: Can you try escaping the special chars in the name using css `[name="vistaConsultaEstadoRUT\:formConsultaEstadoRUT\:numNit"]` or just send the name with escaped chars `"vistaConsultaEstadoRUT\:formConsultaEstadoRUT\:numNit"`

Comment: Scaping the chars with backslash didn't work. And using css gave me this error:
`NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="vistaConsultaEstadoRUT\:formConsultaEstadoRUT\:numNit"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)` 

 Thanks in advance for your help

Code: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("vistaConsultaEstadoRUT\:formConsultaEstadoRUT\:numNit")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *name* attribute of the `<input>` element contains the **`:`** character as in:

```
vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit
```

And **`:`** bears a special effect when used within a [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors). Hence your program fails to find the desired element and raises [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

---

### Solution

To find the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit']")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit']")
  ```

---

### Best practices

As you are invoking `send_keys()` ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit']"))).send_keys("860003020")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit']"))).send_keys("860003020")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: muisca]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)

Comment: Neither worked. Thanks for your answer btw @DebanjanB. The error still appears:
-using `css_selector`, error: 
`NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name='vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit']"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)`

-using `xpath`, error:
`NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='vistaConsultaEstadoRUT:formConsultaEstadoRUT:numNit']"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosHerreraBurbano Check out the update answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @DebanjaB sure! I am so sorry to ask you this but I got stuck again. No worries if you don't answer, I understand is another question. I try to copy an element but it just doesn't make it. `element_to_copy = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_selected((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[class='tipoFilaNormalVerde']")))

print(element_to_copy.text)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosHerreraBurbano This error may be unique and different from what you have asked within this question. If these answers do not fully address your question, please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).